# How to replace NA in one df from another df using for

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, na

I need to fill in all the NAs in one df with the data from another df with the missing information.

```
dfmain <- data.frame (first_column  = c("value_1", [enter image description here][1]NA, NA),
                  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
)                  

dfmissing <- data.frame (first_column  = c("value_to_put", "value_to_put"),
                  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2")
)
```

So is it possible to use loop function to find every NA in one df, put it from another df (all the missing information going one by one, we don't need to select) and delete it in the second df? So we don't need to worry about selecting the right row.

With the following logic?

```
for (i in dfmain[1]) {
  if(is.na(dfmain$first_column[i])){
    dfmain[i,1] <- dfmissing [1,1]
    dfmissing <- dfmissing[-1,]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `NA` values shouldn't be strings - you should use, e.g. `first_column  = c("value_1", NA, NA)`

Answer (score 1):

{dplyr} has a function `rows_patch()` which does exactly this. Note that you've written missing values as strings like `"NA"` - this only works if you use don't quote them, e.g. like `NA`

```r
dfmain <- data.frame(
  first_column  = c("value_1", NA, NA),
  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2", "value_3")
)                  

dfmissing <- data.frame(
  first_column  = c("value_to_put", "value_to_put"),
  second_column = c("value_1", "value_2")
) 

dplyr::rows_patch(
  x = dfmain, 
  y = dfmissing, 
  by = "second_column", 
  unmatched = "ignore"
)
#>   first_column second_column
#> 1      value_1       value_1
#> 2 value_to_put       value_2
#> 3         <NA>       value_3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried the function but got an error:  
! `y` key values must be unique.
ℹ The following rows contain duplicate key values: `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and 128 more.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Is it possible to deal with the duplicates? Ignore them? Or is there another function that can handle the situation

Comment: This sounds like a separate question to me. Try using `dplyr::distinct()` to remove the duplicate values in your second dataset. If this doesn't work you'll need to either edit your question or create a new one.

Comment: Is it possible to put individual numbers to the df, so doing all the rows unique? And just after replacement deleting them

Comment: You'll need to make an edit to your question, that's not enough to go on.

Comment: Couldn't put the link to the post, so there it is: https://imgur.com/a/PPO9fdy I need to put the data from group_correct to group_correct in another df with NA one by one